# retrieve (modification) date of a all file listed in a zip file

Tags: vba, windows, shell, zip

I wrote a VBA macro (partly mine and partyl snippets from the Internet) that lists all files that are contained in all zip files the macro can find in the starting path:

`folder_path = "C:\Users\[MYNAME]\Desktop\prod"`.

This works. It runs through every Folder down to zipArchive which contains multiple zip files with multiple files (no further Folders) within those zip file. I started to let the macro write down some Information about those files such as Name, size,...

NOW the reason I am doing this is that I am interested in the creation date/last modification date of the files within each zip file. So I used

`Range("B" & i).Value = fileNameInZip.DateCreated`

which returns an error saying that the object does not support the method or property…

Can someone help me?

```
Private Sub Get_Information3()
    folder_path = "C:\Users\[MYNMAME]\Desktop\prod"

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1")

    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object 'prod
    Dim oSubFolderSupplier As Object 'Supplier
    Dim oSubFolderCountry As Object
    Dim oSubFolderDatabase As Object
    Dim oSubFolderZipArchive As Object
    Dim oFileinZipArchive As Object
    Dim last_row As Integer

    Dim oApp As Object



    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(folder_path)
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    Dim i, r As Integer
    Dim fileNameInZip As Variant
    Dim Fname As Variant
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1")
    Dim Stringtest As Integer
    Dim test1 As String

    i = 2
    For Each oSubFolderSupplier In oFolder.SubFolders
        For Each oSubFolderCountry In oSubFolderSupplier.SubFolders
            For Each oSubFolderDatabase In oSubFolderCountry.SubFolders
                For Each oSubFolderZipArchive In oSubFolderDatabase.SubFolders
                    For Each oFileinZipArchive In oSubFolderZipArchive.Files



    Fname = Dir(oFileinZipArchive)
    Stringtest = InStrRev(oFileinZipArchive, "\")
    test1 = Left(oFileinZipArchive, Stringtest)


                        If Right(Fname, 4) = ".zip" Then

                             For Each fileNameInZip In oApp.Namespace(test1 & Fname).Items


                             Range("A" & i).Value = fileNameInZip.Name
                             **Range("B" & i).Value = fileNameInZip.DateCreated**


                             i = i + 1

                             Next
                         End If



                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next
    Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: Suggest you put a breakpoint at `Range("A" & i).Value = fileNameInZip.Name`, open the Immediate Window, and inspect the exposed properties of `fileNameInZip`. That may help you get to the info you are after.

Comment: I do know how to open the immediate command and us it for debug printing. but thats it so far until now. how do I expose the properties of   `fileNameInZip`I am confused a bit because  Size, Name work

Comment: Looks like you can only get lastModified and not created.

Comment: DateLastModified doesn’t work either..how can that be ? It works with every other file that is not in a zip

Comment: Misunderstood your intentions

Comment: @DanielTontarra - my mistake - use the Locals Window, not the Immediate to expose the properties.

Answer (score 0):

I just have the same requirement, I found this property: fileNameInZip.ModifyDate can get what you want. Like:

```
For Each fileNameInZip In oZipFolder.Items
    Debug.Print fileNameInZip.path
    Debug.Print fileNameInZip.Size
    Debug.Print fileNameInZip.ModifyDate
Next fileNameInZip
```

get the result of 3rd line of debug.print : 9/28/2020 1:16:46 AM
Hope this helps. Thanks!